# Problem in writing an itegration in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I have 2 columns of arrays. I also have an equation(integration) that uses 2 columns. I need to have the integral values, using two columns values. In the sense that, for each `s` there is `c`.
add the third column which would be the integration result based on a specific index number as an upper and under the limit.
As an example, take a look at the values below:

```
ID=50
s = np.arange(0,100)
c = np.arange(200,300)
lanr=-4.56
lani=-2.33
```

and the integration that I need to be solved is `c(s) * exp(lanr * s) * sin (lani * s)`. Now my problem is adding the third column with the result of the integration between 0,s[ID], which means that and I need to have the integral with detail that I mentioned in the question between `s=0` to `s=ID`.
I have written something below which does not work:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
def f(s):
    return c*(s) * exp(lanr * s) * sin (lani * s)
integ = []
for i in enumerate(s):
    g = c * np.exp(lanr * s) * np.sin(lani * s)

    integrate( f(s), s,0,ID)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for some sort of `cumsum`.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to define "c" inside the forloop. Also you output the result of "c * np.exp(lanr * S) * np.sin(lani * S)" to "g" why don't you use this value anywhere?

Comment: What are the purpose of that for loop ? Seems to me that you are not using that "i" variable. And also, what is the function "integrate" at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  If you want real help provide real information of your problem, for example the error with traceback.  Off hand I can see several problems.  `exp` and `sin` are undefined.  Same for `integrate`.  The `sympy` import is useless.  Show that actual code that you used.

Comment: Note that numpy and sympy can't be mixed. Sympy doesn't understand about numpy arrays nor functions, and numpy doesn't understand about sympy symbols nor functions. Apart from that, a lot of things are extremely unclear, e.g. what is meant by `c(s)`? What is capital `S`? What do you mean by "an integration of two columns"?  Maybe you could add some clarifying plot?

Comment: @hpaulj you are right. The question was not clear. I can say, the more clear way of asking, the less difficulty in finding the answer. Let me try to think about the question again. Thanks

Comment: @JohanC Absolutely you're right. Well, the question is that I have one `c` for each `s` and I need to have the integral with detail that I mentioned in the question between `s=0` to `s=ID`. I could have the parametrized version of the integral but I can not do that for each `c` and `s`. In the end, I wanna have integral values. Again I should apologize for this dummy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is similar to what you're looking for?

At the start, we can try to only work symbolically. `s` is the basic variable. `c` is a function of `s`, in this case writing `c = s + 200` makes `c` such a function.

`f=c*exp(lanr*s)*sin(lani*s)` is a more complicated function of `s`. `print(f)` gives `-(s+200)*exp(-4.56*s)*sin(2.33*s)`.

Now, you seem to be interested in the integral of `f` for `s` going from `0` till some value. Let's call that value `t`. Then, that integral would be a function `g` of `t`.

```py
from sympy import exp, sin, symbols, integrate, lambdify

s, t = symbols('s t')
lanr = -4.56
lani = -2.33
c = s + 200
f = c * exp(lanr * s) * sin (lani * s)
g = integrate(f, (s, 0, t))
```

If only 101 values are needed, we can stay inside sympy:

```py
values = [g.subs(t, ti).evalf() for ti in range(0, 101)]
```

If more numeric calculations are needed, `lambdify()` can convert `g` from sympy to numpy.
Then numpy can also calculate the first 101 values (this works much faster than in sympy, but that is only important if many more calculations are needed):

```
g_np = lambdify(t, g)

import  numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = g_np(x)
```

In this case the result would be

```py
array([  0.        , -17.66531171, -17.80584637, -17.80185932,
       -17.8019015 , -17.80190133, -17.80190133, -17.80190133,
       -17.80190133, -17.80190133, -17.80190133, -17.80190133,
       -17.80190133, -17.80190133, -17.80190133, -17.80190133,
       ...
```

This looks quite strange. Maybe there is some misunderstanding somewhere? Or maybe the original formula has some mistake?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is the most snippets understanding of my problem and question. your answer is quite clear to me, but if I want to do the integral through a for loop, What can be done?
Let me tell you, for each `s` there is a value of `c`. So the first term of the function would be just `c` that is corresponding `s`. Meaning, in each, `s`, there is a value for `c`.
 
I think your result will become ok if could do it in a `for` loop.

Comment: So, `c` is not a formula of `s`, but a list of values?  Is `c` a step function? Or is it continuous? To calculate an integral, `c` should be defined everywhere on the given range.